# How to get user ID on the registration and add in to a wordpress table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to get userID upon new user registration and add the userID to a column of already existing table. My table name is `wp_prli_links` and the column is `wp_prli_links.user_id`

I have added the column to the table using ALTER TABLE

```
ALTER TABLE wp_prli_links ADD wp_prli_links.user_id INT NOT NULL;
```

The table is as follows:

```
+----+---------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+
| id | url                 | slug | redirect_type | group_id | user_id |
+----+---------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+
|  1 | http://example.com/ | 3qqd |           301 |        0 |       0 |
|  2 | http://example.com/ | t8af |           301 |        0 |       0 |
|  3 | http://example.com/ | sjim |           301 |        0 |       0 |
|  4 | http://example.com/ | awfo |           301 |        0 |       0 |
|  5 | http://example.com/ | 6myy |           301 |        0 |       0 |
+----+---------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

I want to add userID captured after a new user registration and add the userid to `wp_prli_links.user_id`

I have tried several variations but none of them captured and added userID to the user_id column.

**Variation 1**

```
function add_to_aff($user_id) {

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 'wp_prli_links', array('wp_prli_links.user_id' => $user_id ), array('%d') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_aff');
```

**Variation 2**

```
function add_to_aff($user_id) {

$user_info = get_userdata( $userid );

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 'wp_prli_links', array('wp_prli_links.user_id' => $user_info->ID ), array('%d') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_aff');
```

I am adding them to `my-theme/functions.php`

None of them seem to work, Can somebody please help me!

**Update**

> After going through much of Stackoverflow, I think, what I am trying
>   to achieve will be best served by `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`. I have
>   to update the `wp_prli_links.user_id` column with user_id (from
>   registration). So that, **each row under the `wp_prli_links.user_id`
>   column will have a  different and unique user_id**.

I just can't figure out how to perform the `UPDATE`. Any help is appreciated!